# Use of uninitialized value in addition

Tags: perl, warnings

The result of the following program gives me a warning.

> Use of uninitialized value in addition (+)

Why uninitialized "+"? How can I fix this?

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise);

my @result_list=();
my @list1=qw(1 23 321 11 324);
my @list2=qw(23 43 46 45 213 435);
@result_list=pairwise { $a + $b } @list1,@list2;
print "@list1\n@list2\n@result_list\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is easy: don't use `pairwise` on arrays of different lengths. Or, replace the missing values with zeroes:

```
my @result_list = pairwise { ($a || 0) + ($b || 0) } @list1, @list2;
```

In Perl 5.10+, you can use the "defined-or" operator `//` instead of the "or" `||`.

Comment: Although in this case, there isn't really any benefit to using `//` instead of `||`, since your default value is 0.